# how to add audio events to "present" slides in an impress.js presentation?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, impress.js

I am trying to add audio events to slides in an impress.js presentation, where a new audio file will play when the "present" slide loads (or where each slide will play back a selection from the same audio file).

I have tried a few options, including impress-audio.js and howl.js, but none really seem to work of being able to trigger specific audio events on each slide. This seems like such a simple concept, but I have not been able to find a good solution. Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit more on what exactly you have tried and the issues faced, probabily sharing the code will help.